# angular what did the 'as' keyword actually doing?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am confusing with the 'as' keyword at the following code, because actually the `this.form.get('topics')` itself is a formArray object then why do I need to return a formArray as a formArray again ? But actually this is true because if I directly return `this.form.get('topics')` then it can't do some of the function such as push, controls and removeAt, but why is this happen ? I have tried to console log both `return this.form.get('topics') as FormArray;` and `return this.form.get('topics')` but still I get a totally same formArray object, but why ? why it is already a formArray I still need to return it as formArray in order to do some operation which formArray can do? what did the 'as' keyword done?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ontime-course-form',
  templateUrl: './ontime-course-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ontime-course-form.component.scss']
})
export class OntimeCourseFormComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({
      topics: new FormArray([])
  })

  addTopic(topic: HTMLInputElement){
      this.topics.push(new FormControl(topic.value))
  }

  removeTopic(topic: FormControl){
    let index = this.topics.controls.indexOf(topic);
    this.topics.removeAt(index);
  }

  get topics(){
    return this.form.get('topics') as FormArray;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).  It doesn't have any affect at runtime (so `console.log()` doesn't know or care about it).  It just tells the compiler what type something is because the compiler can't figure it out itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned this is [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions). This is like casting, telling the compiler the type when it has not been prompted to know by the code.

so here `return this.form.get('topics') as FormArray;`

The compiler would now know that the object being returned is a FormArray. Which is beneficial as the compiler / IDE will now know the shape of the object and about and what properties its has. `.length` etc.

This could be simplified down to giving the function a return type if this style is not desired. The method is called [Type Annotation](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/type-annotation).

```
public get topics(): FormArray <-- type assigned here. {
    return this.form.get('topics');
}
```

Comment: omg, I got it it means that I can even do `return <FormArray>(this.form).get('topics');` !!!! thank you so much

Comment: glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's equivalent to

```
  get topics() : FormArray {
    const result : FormArray  = this.form.get('topics');
    return result;
  }
```

Please refer 
[As Usage](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)

Comment: now I got it thank you so much